# Parsing C# Conditional Compilation statements in roslyn

Tags: c#, parsing, roslyn, conditional-compilation

How do I parse C# conditional compilation statement using Roslyn.

In the following code, I want Roslyn to give the Conditional compilation statement node.

```
public abstract class TestClass
{
    public int Get()
    {
    #if DEBUG
        return 1;
    #else
        return 2;
    #endif
    }
}
```

I don't get conditional compilation node in SyntaxTree and neither it is part of LeadingTrivia of `}` or TrailingTrivia of `{`

What I get in LeadingTrivia of `}` is `"\t\t#endif\r\n\t\t"` and TrailingTrivia of `{` is `"\r\n"` which is not complete conditional compilation statement.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you are willing to consider a non-Roslyn solution, I can describe one where this process is extremely straightforward.

Comment: @ira-baxter it has to be roslyn specifc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse the nodes via visitor (CSharpSyntaxRewriter\Walker) you need to override:

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitIfDirectiveTrivia(IfDirectiveTriviaSyntax node)
{
}

public override SyntaxNode VisitElseDirectiveTrivia(ElseDirectiveTriviaSyntax node)
{
}

public override SyntaxNode VisitEndIfDirectiveTrivia(EndIfDirectiveTriviaSyntax node)
{
}
```

If you want to get this not via visitors, you can do this:

```
node.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<ConditionalDirectiveTriviaSyntax>();
```

You can take a look [here](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) to see what Roslyn generating for your conditional.

**Update**

I checked it, and indeed its kind of complicated here, because its not `Node` of course. The node is just `return 2` or if you write `#define DEBUG` its `return 1`.

So, in case you have that conditional directive inside method you can do something like this:

```
// First get the relevant method (or any other parent block depending in the case)
var method = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();

// Then, you can write method similar to this
static SyntaxTrivia GetConditionalDirectiveTrivia(SyntaxNode node, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    foreach (SyntaxNode syntaxNode in node.DescendantNodes())
    {
        var trivia = syntaxNode.GetLeadingTrivia().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Kind() == kind);
        if (trivia != default(SyntaxTrivia))
            return trivia;
        GetConditionalDirectiveTrivia(syntaxNode, kind);
    }
    return default(SyntaxTrivia);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
GetConditionalDirectiveTrivia(method, SyntaxKind.IfDirectiveTrivia);
```

You can find it in more ways without the Kind but I think its good enough.

Note, that its just an example. I return here only the first trivia.

In your real code, you can write more elegant solution (maybe even an extension method) to get for example `AllTriviaOfKind` or something else that fit your requirements. 
Also, you can return the token trivia or the parent node, if the trivia itself is useless for you, whatever you want\need.

I hope its help.

Comment: I am not using visitors so I tried calling DescendantNodesAndSelf on Method node but I don't see ConditionalDirectiveTriviaSyntax in the list instead there is a BlockSyntax (which is too generic)

Comment: @adeel41 `BlockSyntax` is the parent of all your method body. Within this block you will find statements and then you will find what you need. So if your original node is `MethodDeclerationSyntax` you need to deep into to find what you want.

Comment: @adeel41 I writing from my phone now.. I can update my answer soon and show you exactly how to do that (if you need)

Comment: This is what I get from thae Block node
`
    [0]: SyntaxNodeOrToken Block {
  #if DEBUG
   return 1;
  #else
   return 2;
  #endif
  }
    [1]: SyntaxNodeOrToken OpenBraceToken {
    [2]: SyntaxNodeOrToken ReturnStatement return 2;
    [3]: SyntaxNodeOrToken ReturnKeyword return
    [4]: SyntaxNodeOrToken NumericLiteralExpression 2
    [5]: SyntaxNodeOrToken NumericLiteralToken 2
    [6]: SyntaxNodeOrToken SemicolonToken ;
    [7]: SyntaxNodeOrToken CloseBraceToken }`

Comment: @adeel41 When Ill get back to the office Ill update the answer

Comment: Thanks @dudi-keleti I'll let you know the result

Comment: I've fixed my problem by using SyntaxToken ContainsDirectives property. So on `}` token if ContainsDirectives is true or on `{` token's GetNextToken().ContainsDirectives is true then it is part of directive.

Comment: @adeel41 Yes true. If you just need to know if it contains directive .

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct as I didn't provide complete information.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't get conditional compilation node in SyntaxTree and neither it is part of LeadingTrivia of `}` or TrailingTrivia of `{`

In fact, it's in the `LeadingTrivia` of the `return` keyword in `return 2;`. The lead trivia for `return` is:

- IfDirectiveTrivia (`#if DEBUG`)
- DisableTextTrivia (`return 1;`)
- ElseDirectiveTrivia (`#else`)

Comment: Thanks for giving me some information on how to find that information but not sure if I'll do that way because it looks I've to parse a lot.